# how to parse the json using php?

Tags: php, json

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "clientid": "1",
    "serviceid": null,
    "pid": null,
    "domain": null,
    "totalresults": "2",
    "startnumber": 0,
    "numreturned": 2,
    "products": {
        "product": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "clientid": "1",
                "orderid": "1",
                "pid": "1",
                "regdate": "2015-01-01",
                "name": "Starter",
                "translated_name": "Starter",
                "groupname": "Shared Hosting",
                "translated_groupname": "Shared Hosting",
                "domain": "demodomain.com",
                "dedicatedip": "",
                "serverid": "1",
                "servername": "Saturn",
                "serverip": "1.2.3.4",
                "serverhostname": "saturn.example.com",
                "suspensionreason": "",
                "firstpaymentamount": "12.95",
                "recurringamount": "12.95",
                "paymentmethod": "authorize",
                "paymentmethodname": "Credit Card",
                "billingcycle": "Monthly",
                "nextduedate": "2016-11-25",
                "status": "Terminated",
                "username": "demodoma",
                "password": "xxxxxxxx",
                "subscriptionid": "",
                "promoid": "0",
                "overideautosuspend": "",
                "overidesuspenduntil": "0000-00-00",
                "ns1": "",
                "ns2": "",
                "assignedips": "",
                "notes": "",
                "diskusage": "0",
                "disklimit": "0",
                "bwusage": "0",
                "bwlimit": "0",
                "lastupdate": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                "customfields": {
                    "customfield": []
                },
                "configoptions": {
                    "configoption": []
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "clientid": "1",
                "orderid": "2",
                "pid": "3",
                "regdate": "2015-05-20",
                "name": "Plus",
                "translated_name": "Plus",
                "groupname": "Shared Hosting",
                "translated_groupname": "Shared Hosting",
                "domain": "demodomain2.net",
                "dedicatedip": "",
                "serverid": "2",
                "servername": "Pluto",
                "serverip": "2.3.4.5",
                "serverhostname": "pluto.example.com",
                "suspensionreason": "",
                "firstpaymentamount": "24.95",
                "recurringamount": "24.95",
                "paymentmethod": "paypal",
                "paymentmethodname": "PayPal",
                "billingcycle": "Monthly",
                "nextduedate": "2017-01-20",
                "status": "Active",
                "username": "demodom2",
                "password": "xxxxxxxx",
                "subscriptionid": "",
                "promoid": "0",
                "overideautosuspend": "",
                "overidesuspenduntil": "0000-00-00",
                "ns1": "",
                "ns2": "",
                "assignedips": "",
                "notes": "",
                "diskusage": "0",
                "disklimit": "0",
                "bwusage": "0",
                "bwlimit": "0",
                "lastupdate": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                "customfields": {
                    "customfield": []
                },
                "configoptions": {
                    "configoption": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "option": "Sample Config Option",
                            "type": "dropdown",
                            "value": "Selected option value"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

How can i parse the product details from json
```

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: read up on [json-decode](http://php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use json decode function of php to make object then fetch data from object.

$data = 'write your json response here';

$return = json_decode($data);

print_r($return);

echo $return->result;

Comment: thanks for idea i know upto this see my json from their i want parse my data and i know generally but for this formate i need a support